# Input box won't accept anything ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, data-binding

I have this code, but I can't make it work. The input lines simply won't accept anything. I tried searching all over the place to no avail, so i decided to finally ask the question. 
P.S. I am new to react

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { inputValue: [{item:'', name:''}] }
  handleChange = e => {
    const newValue = [...this.state.inputValue];
    newValue[0][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({inputValue: newValue});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='container jumbotron'>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <FirstInput handleChange={this.handleChange} inputValue={this.state.inputValue[0].name}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <SecondInput handleChange={this.handleChange} inputValue={this.state.inputValue[0].name}/>     
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const FirstInput = (props) => (
  <div>
    <label>First Input</label>
    <input className="form-control" onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.inputValue}/>
  </div>
)

const SecondInput = ({inputValue, handleChange}) => (
  <div>
    <label>Second Input</label>
    <input className="form-control" onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue}/>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to maintain the array as an array of object. The goal is to have first input and second input be the same value. Meaning, changing one input will make the other input the same.

Comment: Issue is with `newValue[0][e.target.name]` your inputs have no name. I think what you meant to do was `newValue[0][name]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `name` attribute defined on your Input elements and hence the value doesn't change. Update your code to

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { inputValue: [{ item: '', name: '' }, { item: '', name: '' }] }
  handleChange = e => {
    const newValue = [...this.state.inputValue];
    newValue[0][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ inputValue: newValue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container jumbotron'>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <FirstInput handleChange={this.handleChange} inputValue={this.state.inputValue[0].name} />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <SecondInput handleChange={this.handleChange} inputValue={this.state.inputValue[0].item} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const FirstInput = (props) => (
  <div>
    <label>First Input</label>
    <input className="form-control" name="name" onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.inputValue} />
  </div>
)

const SecondInput = ({ inputValue, handleChange }) => (
  <div>
    <label>Second Input</label>
    <input className="form-control" name="item" onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your state.  `inputValue: [{item:'', name:''}]` is an array, and handleChange you try to assign string value.

Your code should look like this one:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { 
     firstInput: '',
     secondInput: '' 
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value;
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='container jumbotron'>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <Input 
                label="First Input"
                name="firstInput"
                handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                inputValue={firstInput}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <Input 
                label="First Input"
                name="secondInput"
                handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                inputValue={secondInput}/>     
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Input = (props) => (
  <div>
    {props.label && <label>{props.label}</label>}
    <input 
       className="form-control" 
       onChange={props.handleChange} 
       name={props.name}
       value={props.inputValue}/>
  </div>
)


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```